# Delete list items of multi-view types

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using a ListView with different view types by implementing:

```
public int getViewId();
```

Which works great, but I run into NullPointerExceptions when deleting a certain item because view elements cannot be found on it. I reckon this is due to view recycling where the old position is replaced with the wrong view type.

How can I refresh the layout and make it re-render thoroughly, so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2):

when mutating the underlying list of the adapter, `notifyDataSetChanged` and `notifyDataSetInvalidated` are your friends.

Comment: The `notifyDataSetInvalidated` did it!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the data sources for the ListView (a List object or something) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter.

```
public void updateMyListView(Element elementToRemove){
    listViewData.remove(elementToTemove);
    listView.getAdapter().notifyDatasetChanged(); 
}
```

EDIT: 
Ok, and did you implement the `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` mechanic?